# How can I get rid of crackling noise when playing multiple sounds with SoundPool

Tags: android, soundpool

My app plays a short beep whenever the user touches a tile.  Sounds perfect.  However, if the user drags their finger it will play the beep multiple times in quick succession, which works but also makes a crackling, static kind of noise.  I'm trying to get rid of the crackle.

I've tried many things that have *not* worked:

- Increasing the SoundPool max streams to 8 or 16 - no effect
- incrementing sndPriority so that each call to play() uses a higher priority than the last one - no effect
- calling sp.stop(sndPlaying) on the previous sound - this actually makes the crackle worse
- Tested on two different devices with different Android OS versions, same crackle
- I've tinkered with the sound file in Audacity and I am reasonably confident the crackle is not a problem with the sound file

Code:

```
public void setup() {
  sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
  sndBeep = sp.load(panel.act.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep, 1);
}
public void play() {
  // sp.stop(sndPlaying);   -- this actually makes the crackling noise worse
  // sndPriority++;         -- this had no effect
  sndPlaying = sp.play(sndBeep, 1.0f, 1.0f, sndPriority, 0, sndFreq);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noise happens because of the little pause between the last and the next beep. So, in fact you should decrement the priority on each call.

This should finish the last beep and start the new one only after that.

There's still a chance to get some noise. Simply if the sound contains - even a tiny - noise at beginning or end.

Comment: I changed it to decrease the priority on each call, and set max Streams to 16, which should be enough to never overlap, and the noise is greatly reduced, but I do still hear it occasionally and I'm not sure why.  Any tips on how to change the file to get rid of it?  I've tried adding .02 sec of silence on each end of it.

Comment: Also: if I drag my finger as fast as I can to make lots of repeated noises, I can occasionally get it to just stop playing audio at all.  I've run it through the debugger and everything looks fine in that state.  Restarting the app fixes it.  Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Maybe you really have some tiny noise at beginning or end. The noise overlaps and can occasionally be in the area of human-hearable sound. Can you edit the sound? Make sure you have on frequencies in the lower  KHz area (like < 5KHz) and be totally silent at beginning and end.

Comment: Well it is definitely overlapping, as I have max Streams set to 16.  If I decrease priority and set max Streams to 1, it just skips the beeps that would overlap, which is not the desired behavior.  So it is overlapping the beeps, and most of the time that's fine, but I still hear the noise, usually on the end of the last beep.  I am pretty sure the start and stop of the sound is complete silence.

Comment: So I understand, are you suggesting the problem is that two noises overlap and cause, like, dissonance or something?  Meaning, it's a legitimate consequence of the noises I'm playing?  Because what it sounds like to me is more like Android adding a click that isn't related to the tones being played.

Comment: This overlapping and max streams parameter seems to be not really handled equally on all devices. I use soundpool with max stream of one but still have (on Sony) overlapping sound. On HTC it's waiting/skipping.

Comment: Definitely I think it's dissonance, not a click added by Android. - as long as you dont have a click especially loaded and played

Comment: Thanks for the advice man, I will futz with the beep tone and see what I can do to minimize the crackling.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the cause of that crackle, but I have two suggestions:

1. set the maxStreams bigger than 1, re-increment the priority and see if it has some effects.
2. set setOnLoadCompleteListener before loading your sound file:

   ```
   sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
       @Override
       public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundpool, int sampleId, int status) {
           loaded = true;
       }
   });
   ```

   and then check the flag before you play the file,

   ```
   if (loaded)
       sndPlaying = sp.play(sndBeep, 1.0f, 1.0f, sndPriority, 0, sndFreq);
   ```

Comment: I had already tried 1.  I believe 2 is only necessary when you're loading the file on the fly - I am loading it once at app startup and then playing it over and over.  Thanks though.